# HTML Entities in Twitter API 1.1 ->post

Tags: php, post, twitter, html-entities

So, I'm using Twitter API 1.1 $connection->post to send a tweet. The problem is, when I have a special character, such as an apostrophe in the tweet string i.e:

```
$vinedesc = 'News Reporter's reaction';
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $vinedesc));
```

The tweet is tweeting with HTML entities included i.e:

```
 News Reporter&#39;s reaction
```

How can I stop this from happening? Somebody suggested rawurldecode but the below does not work, I'm guessing I'm not using it correctly given the context:

```
$vinedescraw = 'News Reporter's reaction';
$vinedesc = rawurldecode($vinedescraw);
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $vinedesc));
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, although in my case I knew the source string already had HTML characters embedded. I found this conversion on the PHP site (http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) that instantly cured the problem:

```
$vinedesc=preg_replace_callback("/(&#[0-9]+;)/", function($m) { return mb_convert_encoding($m[1], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES"); }, $vinedescraw);
```

As mentioned Norman Bird's answer, converting to UTF-8 did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
$vinedescraw = 'News Reporter's reaction';
```

has a syntax error, it should be:

```
$vinedescraw = 'News Reporter\'s reaction';
```

Moreover, you shall use rawurlencode() with  `'News Reporter's reaction'` as argument, or rawurldecode() with

```
'News Reporter&#39;s reaction'
```

as argument, to change from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and after trying addslashes(), htmlentities, and all the encode stuff. it turned out that Twitter likes the file type to be UTF-8 and not ANSI or anything else. :-) now my quotes and apostrophe's are fine.